# Windows RT Powershell (PermissionDenied) on New-Object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to instantiate an object in Powershell for Windows RT, but keep getting the following error.

```
PS > $foo = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed
New-Object : Cannot create type. Only core types are supported in this language mode.
At line:1 char:8
+ $foo = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [New-Object], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotCreateTypeConstrainedLanguage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I just spent the last thirty minutes engaged in some pretty heavy Google-fu and was unable to find anything even close to a similar problem, let alone an answer.  My hope is that I just need to configure something; my fear is that Windows RT ships with a crippled version of Powershell.

Does anyone know which case it is?

Answer (score 4):

Yup, Windows RT ships with a locked down version of PowerShell - it operates in ConstrainedLanguageMode which prevents most interaction (prop setters/method calls) with .NET.  It also has a limited command set IIRC.

Comment: As Keith mentioned, on Windows RT PowerShell runs in Constrained Language Mode. You can read more about it and what types of operations are permitted at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn433292.aspx