# How do you add more property values to a custom object

Tags: powershell, object

If I do this

```
$account = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{User="Jimbo"; Password="1234"}
```

How do I add **additional** User and Password values to `$account` without overwriting the existing one?

I cannot pre-populate `$account` from a hashtable. I don't know all the users and passwords at runtime.

Comment: I think we need to see an example of what you are trying to do. Adding new properties is easier if you build the hash table before the `new-object`. `$props = @{User="Jimbo"; Password="1234"}; $props.NewProperty = "Yeah"`

Comment: I feel like marking this as a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353797/powershell-how-to-initialize-array-of-custom-objects

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to use `$account` to store user + pwd credentials, you should declare it as an `array` and add items when you want:

```
$account = @()
$account += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{User="Jimbo"; Password="1234"}
$account += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{User="Jimbo2"; Password="abcd"}
$account += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{User="Jimbo3"; Password="idontusepwds"}
```

Output of `$account`:

```
User   Password    
----   --------    
Jimbo  1234        
Jimbo2 abcd        
Jimbo3 idontusepwds
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. I'll mark that as the answer when the timeout expires.

Comment: @ATtheincredibleaf Your question was about adding property values? This answer is showing how to build an object array

Comment: I would build this in a  loop and avoid the `+=`. Are you limited to PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: Matt is right, your question is a little bit misleading. I just figured out that you probably want to use an array because you want to store multiple user + pwd combinations

Answer (score 28):

The `-Property` parameter of [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/New-Object?view=powershell-3.0) takes a hashtable as argument. You can have the properties added in a particular order if you make the hashtable ordered. If you need to expand the list of properties at creation time just add more entries to the hashtable:

```
$ht = [ordered]@{
  'Foo' = 23
  'Bar' = 'Some value'
  'Other Property' = $true
  ...
}

$o = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $ht
```

If you need to add more properties *after* the object was created, you can do so via the [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Member?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet:

```
$o | Add-Member -Name 'New Property' -Type NoteProperty -Value 23
$o | Add-Member -Name 'something' -Type NoteProperty -Value $false
...
```

or via calculated properties:

```
$o = $o | Select-Object *, @{n='New Property';e={23}}, @{n='something';e={$false}}
```