# C# in PowerShell: Language Mode Not Supported

Tags: c#, powershell, add-type

I am trying to get a very simple script to work in PowerShell, and it keep popping back with the following error:

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. Definition of new types is not supported in this language mode.
At C:\Users\jdkin_000.ATHENA\cs_init.ps1:16 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
```

Here is the script:

```
$Source = @"
using System;

namespace cs1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
```

Any suggestions on how to get this script to work on the exact device that is throwing back the error. The script and similar scripts work on other machines, but when the script contains C#, this machine just doesn't want to play fair.

Comment: What is the PowerShell version on that affected machine? FYI there is a descrepency between the code you supplied and the error: `-OutputType ConsoleApplication`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I must have grabbed one of the earlier attempts.

'PS C:\Users\jdkin_000.ATHENA> get-host'


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 4.0
InstanceId       : 4a8573de-446a-4ca1-a535-2b0205ce64e0
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Comment: Can't get the reply to do what I want it to... Here is the best I can get for it, before the 5 minute comment editing timer is up. =(

`PS C:\Users\jdkin_000.ATHENA> get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 4.0
InstanceId       : 4a8573de-446a-4ca1-a535-2b0205ce64e0
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace`

Comment: Please, edit your question, don't add details to comments.

Answer (score 2):

Try running this:

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
```

Here is the link explaining the LanguageMode.  I assume you are in a mode that restricts the ability to define new types.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn433292.aspx

Edit: Based on the Windows RT 8.1 OS, (
[Windows RT Powershell (PermissionDenied) on New-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504499/windows-rt-powershell-permissiondenied-on-new-object))
It doesn't appear that it can be done.

Comment: PowerShell returns "ConstrainedLanguage" (Is there a way around this? (specifically for C++ and C#))

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Here's your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504499/windows-rt-powershell-permissiondenied-on-new-object  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell also may switch to ConstrainedLanguage mode when there is no space available on system drive.